# How to prove a smaller collection of subset of E has smaller σ-algebra on E

Tags: measure-theory

I just started studying Measure Theory, and we covered sigma-algebra and are given the exercise as follow:
"Let C and D be two collections of subsets of E. Show the following statement: If C is in D, then σC is in σD"
Since "σC" is supposed to be the smallest σ-algebra that contains C (similarly for σD), then I assume this question is asking how to prove a smaller collection of subsets of E has smaller σ-algebra on E, and how can we prove that?

Comment: Strict containment is not true in general, if that's what you're getting at.  For example, if $C$ is not a $\sigma$-algebra and $D=\sigma(C)$, then $\sigma(C)=\sigma(D)$.  So the best you can hope for is $C \subseteq D \Rightarrow \sigma(C) \subseteq \sigma(D)$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any sigma algebra that contains $D$ also contains $C$. In particular the smallest sigma algebra that contains $D$ contains $C$. Hence the result.